# Can I meet NEC class 2 or 3 requirements by fusing a 120v circuit at 0.5a?

Tags: transformer, fuses

I am installing a device that operates at 120 VAC, and I wish to use a class 2 wiring method. The device is rated at 0.1 A, and I want to know if I can simply fuse a 120 V circuit to meet class 2 requirements, or if I need a transformer or some other kind of current limiting device?

Comment: Class 2 requirements? What are they? What country do they apply to?

Comment: The NEC applies to the US.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a fuse can not make a circuit Class 2. I just looked briefly in my 1996 hard copy of NEC. You can read the current edition online free at the NFPA web site if you sign up. It is free, but you may need to give them your name, mailing address and email.